# TFS pending changes window equivalent in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn

Is there a way to view pending changes in Eclipse like TFS? Tried installing Subclipse and even Subversive, but could not find anything. Would like to be able to see what all files are checked out instead of keeping a note manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like the [Subclipse "Workspace synchronization"](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/teamSupport/workspace_synch.php)

[image: SVN Workspace Synchronization]

> SVN Workspace Synchronization is shown in the '`Synchronize View`' after a click on a '`Team>Synchronize`' menu item or '`Synchronize`' button on '`Team`' toolbar of the '`Team Synchronizing`' perspective.
>   **It provides a probability to inspect the changes types of your local copy from the remote one**.